# Modification in serializer.data format before returning jsonresponse

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting-

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "url": "https://emiactech.com/",
        "title": "",
        "blog_post": 0,
        "index_count": 0,
        "external_urls": "[{'url': '#', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/', 'title': u''}, {'url': 'https://www.facebook.com/EMIACTechnologies/', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/', 'title': u'Facebook'}, {'url': 'https://twitter.com/emiactech', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/', 'title': u'Twitter'}, {'url': 'mailto:sales@emiactech.com', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/', 'title': u'sales@emiactech.com'}, {'url': 'http://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226?ref=ThemeFusion', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/about-us/', 'title': u''}, {'url': '#tab-bdf4143f2c7b5609720', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/services/', 'title': u'Web Design and Development'}, {'url': '#tab-70d2572b15f9a5ac477', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/services/', 'title': u'Content Development'}, {'url': '#tab-c59a00bf26295e6ed39', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/services/', 'title': u'Digital Marketing'}, {'url': 'https://emiactech.com', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/cqpim-client/', 'title': u'Home'}, {'url': 'http://themetf.com', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/portfolio-items/humsafar-love/', 'title': u' theme-tf'}, {'url': 'http://shades.salon', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/portfolio_category/jquery/', 'title': u'http://shades.salon'}, {'url': 'http://Project%20URL', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/portfolio_category/jquery/', 'title': u' View Project '}, {'url': 'http://samacharjagat.com', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/portfolio_category/jquery/', 'title': u'http://samacharjagat.com'}]",
        "external_count": 13
    }]
```

in `serializer.data` . external_urls key data is the type of string. I need this key data either in the form of list or dictionary something like this;

```
[{'url': '#', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/', 'title': u''}, {'url': 'https://www.facebook.com/EMIACTechnologies/', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/', 'title': u'Facebook'}, {'url': 'https://twitter.com/emiactech', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/', 'title': u'Twitter'}, {'url': 'mailto:sales@emiactech.com', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/', 'title': u'sales@emiactech.com'}, {'url': 'http://themeforest.net/item/avada-responsive-multipurpose-theme/2833226?ref=ThemeFusion', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/about-us/', 'title': u''}, {'url': '#tab-bdf4143f2c7b5609720', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/services/', 'title': u'Web Design and Development'}, {'url': '#tab-70d2572b15f9a5ac477', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/services/', 'title': u'Content Development'}, {'url': '#tab-c59a00bf26295e6ed39', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/services/', 'title': u'Digital Marketing'}, {'url': 'https://emiactech.com', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/cqpim-client/', 'title': u'Home'}, {'url': 'http://themetf.com', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/portfolio-items/humsafar-love/', 'title': u' theme-tf'}, {'url': 'http://shades.salon', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/portfolio_category/jquery/', 'title': u'http://shades.salon'}, {'url': 'http://Project%20URL', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/portfolio_category/jquery/', 'title': u' View Project '}, {'url': 'http://samacharjagat.com', 'page': 'https://emiactech.com/portfolio_category/jquery/', 'title': u'http://samacharjagat.com'}]
```

<---------------------UPDATE------------------->

serializer.py

```
class WebsiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Website
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py

```
class Website(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True,)
    blog_post = models.IntegerField(default=170, blank=True,)
    index_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True,)
    external_urls = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    external_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True,)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "website"
```

Comment: show your serializer and external_urls field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [serializermethodfield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
from ast import literal_eval


class WebsiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     external_urls = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

     def get_external_urls(self, obj):
         # return eval(obj.external_urls) will work
         return literal_eval(obj.external_urls)
```

Comment: data come like ["[", "{", "'", "u", "r", "l", "'", ":", " ", "'", "#", "'", ",","]","]

Comment: please add model field description